# Selenium RC Safari Keyboard (SendKeys) not working

Tags: selenium, safari, keyboard, selenium-rc

I'm running a Selenium RC 2.48.0 server on a Mac using the Safari plugin for Selenium 2.48.0. I'm running my tests on a PC in Visual Studio with Selenium.net 2.48.0 with a Remote web driver for Safari.

Here's how I create my Safari RC Remote web driver connection:

```
RemoteWebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("http://192.168.50.13:4444/wd/hub"),DesiredCapabilities.Safari());
```

I try to send keys to the web driver using

```
driver.Keyboard.SendKeys("300001");
```

Problem: driver.Keyboard.SendKeys does not work. Instead they throw an exception. (The same commands work fine with a local Chrome Webdriver.

Selenium 2.48 is currently (at the time I'm writing this) the latest available Selenium version for Safari.

[image: Selenium RC vs Local]

Here's the exception:

An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in WebDriver.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Unknown command: {"id":"15ugwifcwkos","name":"sendKeysToActiveElement","parameters":{"value":["3","0","0","0","0","1"]}} (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)

Command duration or timeout: 4 milliseconds

Build info: version: '2.48.0', revision: 'b7b081a', time: '2015-10-07 15:48:56'

System info: host: '--------.local', ip: '192.168.50.13', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.11.2', java.version: '1.8.0_91'

Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriver

Capabilities [{browserName=safari, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, version=9.0.2, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, platform=MAC, secureSsl=true}]

Session ID: null

Comment: Safari seems to lack the interactions API. See https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/4136. We have excluded Safari in our test which sends keys to the browser.